# remove white gap from marquee

Tags: html, tags

There is a white gap on a marquee.

I put a long sentence (Breaking news Breaking news Breaking news Breaking news Breaking news Breaking news Breaking news) but it keeps on going then the B touches touches the edge

> **B**reaking news Breaking news Breaking news Breaking news...

It doesn't come out from the other end until everything goes through

> s

^above is the sentence almost going to come out of the other end^

I have searched all over google (I even found a hack on google(search "marquee html"))

```html
<marquee>here is the text I repeat it over and over again it keeps going and going but the beginning wouldn't come out until I touch it</marquee>
```

Comment: If you include your code it will be easier for people to help :)

Comment: Please be aware that the `<marquee>` tag is obsolete, and it is not considered good practice to use it. It does work, but does not have any features to allow you to configure it. If you use it, you just have to accept the way it works.

Comment: Ok I'll keep that in my mind (I'm a beginner coder and self thought myself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should not use the `<marquee>` tag as it is deprecated, or obsolete rather, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Maybe try for a javascript/jquery solution. There are plenty of plugins for this

*Edit*

I found this jQuery Marquee Plugin with an option for no gap like you are looking for. Here is an example

```js
$('.marquee').marquee({
  direction: 'left'
});
```

```css
.marquee {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.4.0/jquery.marquee.min.js'></script>

<div class="marquee" data-duplicated='true' data-direction='left'>jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world</div>
```

*2023 EDIT*

Can use CSS animations:

```css
.marquee {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.marquee p {
  padding-left: 50%;
  color: red;
  animation: marquee 7s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <p>Enjoy this CSS marquee! 2023!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you insert a snippet I'm not that great and javascript (I self thought myself how to do html)